# How do obtain the @@identity value after using SqlCeDataAdapter.Update ()

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-ce

I had my application running on Sql Server 2008, I decided to change the Database to Sql Server CE since I was only using it for one computer. Now, I had to add other assemblies, and I had to change `SqlDataAdapter` to `SqlCeDataAdapter`. I also had to change the way of retrieving the last identity value created in a table after inserting a new record, this means I was using the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` method and now I'm trying to obtain the `@@identity` value. The problem is that if I use `SqlCeDataAdapter.Update()` this closes the connection after inserting and the `@@identity` value is reset to null. How do I get the `@@identity` value then?

Comment: Add a handler to the DataAdapter’s RowUpdated event to SELECT @@IDENTITY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a handler to the DataAdapter’s RowUpdated event to SELECT @@IDENTITY.

This will query the databases before the connection is closed so the ID value is still available.